# Parametrization of a curve $r(\phi) = \cos(\phi)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis

We have this curve
$r(\phi) = \cos(\phi)$

And we want to parameterize it.

In lectures we have done the following:

$$
x(\phi) = r\cdot \cos{(\phi)} = \cos^2(\phi)\\
y(\phi) =r\cdot \sin{(\phi)} = \sin{(\phi)} \cdot \cos{(\phi)}
$$
Why do we multiply the $x$ and $y$ coordinates by $\cos$ and $\sin$ ?

Can anybody please explain what we just done and why?

Is this general, to multiply by $\sin$ and $\cos$ to parameterize a curve?

Comment: Yes it is general if the curve is itself given in polar coordinate form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a point $P(x,y)$ on a circle of radius $r$ centered at the origin. Let $\phi$ be the angle to the horizontal determined by $P$. By definition,
$$
\cos \phi = \frac{x}{r}
$$
and
$$
\sin \phi = \frac{y}{r}.
$$
Rearrange to recover the familiar formulas you cited.

Answer (score 1):

The procedure you did is not the only way to parameterize a curve.

First, you have initially described the curve in terms of its polar coordinates. You have the angle $\phi$ and you use the formula $r=\cos(\phi)$ to find the radius.
Now you have both the angle and radius to a point, which perfectly describes a point in the plane. You can set $\phi$ to some value and you immediately find a point on the curve.

To find more points on the curve, you can use $\phi$ as a parameter. Let $\phi$ increase or decrease, compute a new $r$ for each $\phi,$ and plot each pair $(r,\phi)$ as a point in polar coordinates. This will trace part of the curve.

What this says is that the curve **was already parameterized** when it was first described to you.

But perhaps you are not satisfied using polar coordinates. You might want to describe the curve in Cartesian coordinates instead.
But you might still want a parameterization.

You can then convert the polar coordinates of your existing parameterization to Cartesian.
And there is a standard conversion from polar to Cartesian:

$$ x = r \cos(\phi), $$
$$ y = r \sin(\phi). $$

All you did to make this a “parameterization” was that you took your existing parameterization (in which $r$ is a function of $\phi$) in order to write $x$ as a function of $\phi$ and also write $y$ as a function of $\phi.$

In summary, the multiplications by the sine and cosine have to do with converting from polar coordinates to Cartesian. They don’t occur if you start with Cartesian coordinates or if you leave the parameterization in polar coordinates.